# The limit of a certain cases function when x approaches to infinity

Tags: limits

I have a little question about the limit of the next function: $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x ,  \text{ x mod 2 = 0 }
\\\\
x^2,  \text{ x mod 2 = 1 }
\end{cases}$$

when $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. Now, is $ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty $? because we can say that as we proceed with the values of $x$ such that he approaches infinity, even though the function is not continuous, we still get infinite.

Comment: Not every real number is either even or odd.  What, for instance, is $f(\pi)$?

Comment: I am sorry. Got confused while writing. I will fix it

Comment: As to the content of what you are asking about, you need to go back and read again the definition of what it means to say $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.  The definition of this has nothing to do with continuity and does not care what the actual values are or how they are in relation to one another beyond what the definition says.  We say that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ if and only if for every $M$ there exists an $X$ such that for all $x>X$ you have $f(x)>M$.  This function, once defined properly, will certainly satisfy that.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's what I thought when I remembered the definition of function approaches infinity. So if I define the conditions properly as I wanted to, you say that it has nothing to do with the continuity of the function, right? because the values will eventually grow and pass  every $M>0$ we choose.

Comment: How do we interpret $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ if we are only concerned with even/odd inputs? What about all the other $x$ values? How do we define their output? As for now I would say the limit does not exist.

Comment: @imranfat I have already said that I got confused while writing. I am sorry! it has fixed.

Comment: What is $ f(\pi) $ ?

Comment: I think the $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ part needs to changed into integers, not all real numbers

Comment: @imranfat Again mistake. see the new edit

Comment: You edited “$x$ is even” to “$x \bmod 2 = 0$.” I don't see the difference.  In particular, I don't see how this function is defined for non-integer or irrational $x$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You right. I will change the domain to integers. I am sorry.

Comment: Ah, good.  Can you show $\lim_{x\to\infty} x = \infty$?  Because $f(x) \geq x$ for all nonnegative integers $x$.